# cross-compile for amazon ec2 micro

Tags: amazon-ec2, cmake, cross-compiling, toolchain, wt

I'm trying to install latest wt on amazon ec2 micro (free tier). it runs out of memory during the compilation.

How can I compile the wt on another system (i have i7 laptop with 8gb of ram)?

I was hoping that I can run cmake with some option and would get a Makefile that I need with all the gcc options but I can't find how to do that. both of my systems are 64bit.

Comment: one option that i'm exploring is to export the virtual machine but that's a different way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Run a temporary m1.small, c1.medium, or larger EC2 instance, do the compilation there, then terminate the instance.

The systems will match and and it will only cost a dime or two.

Alternatively, you can switch your t1.micro to a larger size temporarily, do the compilation, then switch it back.

Comment: that's what i'm about to do but I also want to know a way to cross-compile things for ec2